# Change $scope value after http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am trying to show different divs depending the response I get from an http request.

```
$scope.firstStep = true;
$scope.secondStep = false;
$scope.thirdStep = false;

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api-web/ec/cadastro/recuperar-acesso',
  data: {
    filiacao: $scope.currentFiliacao,
    cnpj: $scope.currentCNPJ
  },
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).then(function(res){
  $scope.firstStep === false;

  if (res.data.code === -1) {
    $timeout( function (){
      $scope.secondStep === true; //here is the bug, it dont change to true
      console.log("second", $scope.secondStep);
    }, 3000)
  } 
})
```

I tried several things, like $apply(), _defer, switch from === to =
... and I have no idea why its happening.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Just for sanity, your code does stop in the `if (res.data.code === -1) {...}` statement if you put a breakpoint correct?

Comment: exactly. correct.

Comment: Just a heads up `$scope.firstStep === false;` will never work to set a variable. That's checking the value.

Comment: The === operator does not set a value. The ==, too. The right thing is only one =

Comment: But the OP said that they have tried switching from `===` to `=` in the note below the code.

Comment: I know. This was a desperate attempt.

Comment: Based on the code, if you switch `===` to `=` (as you say you've already tried), `secondStep` _will_ be set to true, unless there's some other code that's also somehow changed that variable in parallel (which there isn't any evidence of in the code you posted).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as either a typo or unable to be reproduced, since the code posted ***clearly would be solved by changing `===` to `=` (comparison vs assignment)***, even if the OP suggested they tried that.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't this work?

```
$timeout( function (){
  $scope.secondStep = true;
  $scope.apply();
  console.log("second", $scope.secondStep);
}, 3000)
```

Comment: I feel like `$scope.apply();` inside `$timeout` will throw an error because the digest cycle is already happening, especially since it's coming right after setting `$scope.secondStep` and `$timeout` also invokes the digest cycle.

Comment: I wouldn't use `$timeout` at all unless you actually need a timeout.  Use `$applyAsync`

Comment: @zero298 I'm guessing OP's use of $timeout was for some kind of debugging purpose, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @JoshBeam I don't work with Angular 1 since a while, I don't remember the "rules" of the digest cycle. Maybe (or probably) you are right. Anyway, I can't even figure out why he is using this $timeout :S

Comment: `$scope.apply()` is almost always unnecessary, unless you are purposely invoking some outside code that is changing the DOM without angular's knowledge.  Most of the time, if you are feeling like using `$scope.apply()`, there is probably something else wrong.